# Make a function in Javascript that reads text file into a string and search characters to change them

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel-5

I'm developing a web app for my social service, my problem is that i need to read a text file that is actually an html file that is in my local folder.

In that file i need to find some values and change them to the ones i have selected in my app.

The main objective for my app is to change the images that one project uses to the ones selected on my app and i want to just read the html file and update the "src" values of the html to the ones the user have selected on my app.

I havent found something similar to what i want to and the ones that i tried im having trouble understanding it or it wont work.

This is the html that i want to read and change some values

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Escenario Virtual de Imagenes</title>



    <script src="js/aframe.min.js"></script>
     <script>


//variables de estimulos dentro del arreglo de secuencias//
        var neutro='img/negro.png';
        var instruccionesImagenes='img/Imagenes_instrucciones.png';
        var imagen1='img/1.jpg'; <--- i want to change this number of the path of all.
        var imagen2='img/2.jpg';
        var imagen3='img/3.jpg';
        var imagen4='img/4.jpg';
        var imagen5='img/5.jpg';
        var imagen6='img/6.jpg';
        var imagen7='img/7.jpg';
        var imagen8='img/8.jpg';
        var imagen9='img/9.jpg';
        var imagen10='img/10.jpg';
        var imagen11='img/11.jpg';
        var imagen12='img/12.jpg';
        var imagen13='img/13.jpg';
        var imagen14='img/14.jpg';
        var imagen15='img/15.jpg';
        var imagen16='img/16.jpg';
        var imagen17='img/17.jpg';
        var imagen18='img/18.jpg';
        var imagen19='img/19.jpg';
        var imagen20='img/20.jpg';
        var evaluacion='img/sam.png';
        var bienvenida='img/inicio.png';
        var imagenes=new Array([bienvenida],['img/OC.png'],['img/instruccion2.png'],['img/OA.png'],[neutro],[instruccionesImagenes],[imagen1],[imagen2],[imagen3],[imagen4],[imagen5],[evaluacion],[neutro],[imagen6],[imagen7],[imagen8],[imagen9],[imagen10],[evaluacion],[neutro],[imagen11],[imagen12],[imagen13],[imagen14],[imagen15],[evaluacion],[neutro],[imagen16],[imagen17],[imagen18],[imagen19],[imagen20],[evaluacion],['img/finalizar.png']);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    // * Funcion para cambiar la imagen 
var imagen = 0;//contador de cambio de posicion
function cambiar()
{
    if(imagen < imagenes.length)
    {
          document.querySelector('a-image').setAttribute('src', imagenes[imagen]);
          if (imagenes[imagen]==neutro)
           {

             setTimeout("cambiar()", 30000);//si la imagen del array es neutro entonces que solo pase 15 segundos
             document.getElementById('sonido').setAttribute('sound', 'src', 'narrativas/relax.mp3' );

           }else if (imagenes[imagen]==bienvenida) 
           {   
                setTimeout("cambiar()", 13000);
                //document.getElementById('sonido').setAttribute('sound', 'src', 'narrativas/1.mp3' );
           } else if (imagenes[imagen]==instruccionesImagenes) 
           {
            setTimeout("cambiar()", 15000);//si la imagen del array es  evaluacion entonces que solo pase 10 segundos
            //document.getElementById('sonido').setAttribute('sound', 'src', 'narrativas/5.mp3' );
            // TODO colocar imagene de instruccuiones
           } 
           else if (imagenes[imagen]==evaluacion) 
           {
            setTimeout("cambiar()", 15000);//si la imagen del array es  evaluacion entonces que solo pase 10 segundos
            document.getElementById('sonido').setAttribute('sound', 'src', 'narrativas/evaluacion.mp3' );
           } else if (imagenes[imagen]=='img/OC.png') //si la imagen del array es  ojos cerrados entonces que recorra el time a 2 minutos
           {
           document.getElementById('sonido').setAttribute('sound', 'src', 'narrativas/2.mp3' );
           setTimeout("cambiar()", 70000);
           }
             else if (imagenes[imagen]=='img/instruccion2.png')//si la imagen del array es  la instruccion ojos abiertos entonces que recorra el time a  7 segundos
              {
           document.getElementById('sonido').setAttribute('sound', 'src', 'narrativas/3.mp3' );
           setTimeout("cambiar()", 15000)
              }
             else if (imagenes[imagen]=='img/OA.png') //si la imagen del array es  ojos abiertos entonces que recorra el time a 2 minutos
             {
           document.getElementById('sonido').setAttribute('sound', 'src', 'narrativas/4.mp3' );
            setTimeout("cambiar()", 60000);
             }else if (imagenes[imagen]=='img/finalizar.png')
              {
              document.getElementById('sonido').setAttribute('sound', 'src', 'narrativas/8.mp3' );
              }
           else//si la imagen del array es  la foto 1.2.3.4.5 entonces que recorra el time a 30 segundos
           {
           //document.getElementById('sonido').setAttribute('sound', 'src', 'sound/music.webm' );
            setTimeout("cambiar()", 15000);//15 segundos iaps

           }
           imagen=imagen+1;
    }
}

    /**

     * Función que se ejecuta una vez cargada la página

     */

     onload=function()

     {

      //setTimeout("", 30000);
      cambiar();

    }


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a-scene >
     <!--controles leapmotion-->
<a-entity camera="near: 0.01" look-controls >
  <a-entity leap-hand="hand: left;"></a-entity>
  <a-entity leap-hand="hand: right;"></a-entity>
</a-entity>

        <!--cursor-->


        <a-sky src="img/cielo.png" ></a-sky>
            <!--<a-light type="ambient" color="#222"></a-light>
        piso del entorno virtual-->
        <a-circle color="black" material="opacity:0.2" radius="60" position="0 -10 0" rotation="-90 0 0" ></a-circle>

        <!--Voz de Recomendador-->
<!--
        <a-entity id="play" geometry="primitive: circle" material="color: yellow" position="-10 3 0" sound="src: sound/music.webm; volume:0.89 ;  on: click" ></a-entity>

                <a-entity cursor-listener geometry="primitive: circle" material="color: black" position="10 3 0" ></a-entity>
-->

    <!--musica de inicio-->         
     <a-entity id="sonido" geometry="primitive: circle" material="color: yellow " position="-3 30 0" sound="src: 'sound'; volume:5;autoplay:true " >

     </a-entity>


        <!--pantalla  donde se muestran las imagenes-->
        <a-image  src=" " height="8" width="15"  position="0 2 -8"  rotation="0 0 0" ></a-image>

    </a-scene>

</body>
</html>
```

So the result that i need is to change the values of the src for it to change to the images that the user wants.
Thank you in advance ive been stuck on this for 1 month and im really stressed about it because im not so good at coding.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: i only tried the basic function for reading a file but i dont have a clue of how to search and replace characters where i want

Comment: Regex is my immediate answer..

Comment: Something like that: https://jsbin.com/xosotar/2/edit?js,console. It can't be answer because your question is off-topic but I hope it will help you..

Comment: And this is what that regex means: https://regex101.com/r/He4VX2/1

Comment: Thank you very much i will try this, ill let you know how it went.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend creating an HTML template file instead.

#### templateHtml.js

```
module.exports = `<html>
    <body>
       <p>Some HTML file that follows a template.</p>
       <script>
          var a = $VAR_A$;
          var b = $VAR_B$;
       </script>
    </body>
</html>`;
```

Then creating a helper method that call takes in your variables to replaces the template variable placeholders.

#### generateHtml.js

```
const template = require('./templateHtml');

module.exports.generateHtml = (values = { VAR_A: 1, VAR_B: 2 }) => {
   let htmlPage = template;
   Object.keys(values).forEach(key => {
     htmlPage = htmlPage.replace(`$${key}$`, values[key]); 
   });
   return htmlPage;
}
```

Then you can tie it all together like this.

#### index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { generateHtml } = require('./generateHtml');
const values = getValues(); //Some external call to get your values;
const html = generateHtml(values);
fs.writeFileSync("./myFileName.html", html);
```

Comment: Looks good! just one question  "htmlPage = htmlPage.replace(`$${key}$`, values[key]); " can you explain me that line?

Comment: Well I used $ symbol to make the template variables stand out, you can use anything you like for example double underscore works well too `__VAR_B__`, etc.